# How to export Window Service Configuration (include UserName&Password) programmatically?

Tags: c#, service, window

As titled, or is there a way to do that?

Because for IIS Application pool, it does provide command line utility that allows me to export the application pool with configuration setting includes the user Identity with Password.

Which allows me to delete application pool and recreate it for upgrading our application without needed to prompt for process identity User Name and Password again.

So I would like to implement the same logic for upgrading my Window Service Application, by exporting the Window Service Configuration (including process identity User Name & Password) and reinstall a new version of Window Service with same Window Service Configuration and identity.

Comment: You should be able to implement the `ServerManager` class; this should allow you to create your own `Application Pool` pragmatically.  Which allows you to specify all aspects.

Comment: @Greg I am talking about Exporting Window Service Configuration like what I did for Application Pool